# How does Spark model treat vector column?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

How will method in spark threat a vector assembler column? For example, if I have longitude and latitude column, is it better to assemble them using vector assembler then put it into my model or it does not make any difference if I just put them directly(separately)?

Example1:

```python
loc_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['long', 'lat'], outputCol='loc')
vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['loc', 'feature1', 'feature2'], outputCol='features')
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[loc_assembler, vector_assembler, lr])
```

Example2:

```python
vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['long', 'lat', 'feature1', 'feature2'], outputCol='features')
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vector_assembler, lr])
```

What is the difference? Which one is better?

Comment: I have added the example @dennlinger.. Could you help me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be any difference simply because, in both your examples, the final form of the `features` column will be the same, i.e. in your 1st example, the `loc` vector will be broken back into its individual components.

Here is short demonstration with dummy data (leaving the linear regression part aside, as it is unnecessary for this discussion):

```python
spark.version
#  u'2.3.1'

# dummy data:
df = spark.createDataFrame([[0, 33.3, -17.5, 10., 0.2],
                              [1, 40.4, -20.5, 12., 2.2],
                              [2, 28., -23.9, -2., -1.7],
                              [3, 29.5, -19.0, -0.5, -0.2],
                              [4, 32.8, -18.84, 1.5, 1.8]
                             ],
                              ["id","lat", "long", "other", "label"])

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline

loc_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['long', 'lat'], outputCol='loc')
vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['loc', 'other'], outputCol='features')
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[loc_assembler, vector_assembler])

model = pipeline.fit(df)
model.transform(df).show()
```

The result is:

```python
+---+----+------+-----+-----+-------------+-----------------+
| id| lat|  long|other|label|          loc|         features|
+---+----+------+-----+-----+-------------+-----------------+
|  0|33.3| -17.5| 10.0|  0.2| [-17.5,33.3]|[-17.5,33.3,10.0]|
|  1|40.4| -20.5| 12.0|  2.2| [-20.5,40.4]|[-20.5,40.4,12.0]|
|  2|28.0| -23.9| -2.0| -1.7| [-23.9,28.0]|[-23.9,28.0,-2.0]|
|  3|29.5| -19.0| -0.5| -0.2| [-19.0,29.5]|[-19.0,29.5,-0.5]|
|  4|32.8|-18.84|  1.5|  1.8|[-18.84,32.8]|[-18.84,32.8,1.5]| 
+---+----+------+-----+-----+-------------+-----------------+
```

i.e. the `features` column is arguably identical with your 2nd example (not shown here), where you do not use the intermediate assembled feature `loc`...